# 3 Histograms on one axis - Matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, graphing

I am trying to create a graph that has 3 histograms on one axis. I want them to overlap each with a different color. The insides are semi-transparent.

Whenever I use multiple colors like RGB with alpha 0.5, the colors overlap and create a nasty color.

How would I portray the 3 graphs without producing a nasty color? I still want the graphs to overlap in the same nature, just in a way that is aesthetically pleasing. I have seen graphs that overlap, but you can still see each histograms color distinctly. Thanks

Comment: Since "nasty color" is quite subjective, this can probably not be answered. However, if you have a picture (you say "I've seen graphs...") you may include it here or link to it, such that people know what you are looking for. Also adding some [mcve] of the issue, would allow people to more easily provide you with an answer.

Comment: https://ibb.co/dpaWSF link to ugly grpah

Comment: Yeah, well, as I said, I would be more interested in a picture of a "non-ugly" graph to know what you are looking for.

Comment: good graph http://ibb.co/h6Bc1a

Comment: The non-ugly graphs contain overlapping colors, too. What do you define as nasty colors and nice colors then?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the colors from what you call "good graph" as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)

x1 = np.random.rand(15)*3
x2 = np.random.rayleigh(size=15)
x3 = np.random.binomial(3,0.7,size=15)

bins= np.linspace(0,4,11)
kw = dict(bins=bins, histtype='step', fill=True)
plt.hist(x1, fc=(.14,.57,.14,.4), ec=(.14,.57,.14, 1), **kw)
plt.hist(x2, fc=(.16,.16,1.0,.4), ec=(.16,.16,1.0, 1), **kw)
plt.hist(x3, fc=(1.0,.14,.14,.4), ec=(1.0,.14,.14, 1), **kw)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The difference is, when the colors overlap on the good graph, they don't seem to mix as much. Everything just looks better, even when all 3 colors mix

Comment: I'll test it out @importanceofbeingearnest

Comment: The colors in the graph you call "good" and the colors in my answer are exactly the same, right? So I'm not sure what else you want.